# Using an email system to email an attachment generated within iOS

Tags: ios, email, crash

I'm currently developing an app using Occipital Structure camera. I want to have the ability to take the 3D scan (image) and zip file that the camera generates, and use a service like SendGrid to email the customer in the background after filling out the registration form.

The current problem with SendGrid is that it crashes on me every time I try to send the email, and I'm not sure if iOS is truly supported (used an old github repo).

If you guys can make any other suggestions or link to any articles, that would be tremendously helpful!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When asking a question about a crash you need to include the stack trace and relevant code. As it stands, this question is incredibly difficult (nearly impossible) to answer.

Comment: Sorry! Newbie here. I can't seem to copy and paste the code here, because I'm not able to debug due to the lightning port being occupied by the camera itself. I guess I'm more focused on services that developers use in order to achieve the above. My theory is that SendGrid isn't supported

Comment: You can get the crash log from the device after its crashed (even if not attached to the debugger) in Xcode -> Window -> Devices -> Crash Logs (it'll take a long time to load)

Comment: Also, you should try to replicate the issue without the camera.  If it is the emailing that is crashing, change your app to send a test email so that you can be connected to the debugger.